# Where is info in Samba Server, Linux, which correlates PID with user SID?

Tags: c, linux, events, server, samba

SMBD should provide such a table, it cannot operate otherwise. I have an event from kernel module on file open, removal, read/write and close. I have a process ID (PID) value. I know than samba often forks itself, thus it has a PID value. I need to find a table in memory or on disk to find out user credentials. All that info is got in USER mode via daemon working. Source of samba is too big to dig into it, so, please, help me. May be I am wrong about such a table, but everything shows that it exists somewhere.

I tried to examine samba code. But did not succeed.

Comment: It seems unlikely that if such a table existed, it would be stored on disk.  However, I doubt that there is a single, unified table anywhere of all those correspondences.  But supposing that there were, how do you imagine gaining access to it or using it?

Comment: By hacking samba I suppose.

Comment: Hmmm.  I took you to mean that you wanted to locate the physical storage containing the data, but if the idea is that you will hack Samba, then you need to know where and how that data is managed in the source code.